# Reactjs Unexpected token Error Only On Windows, Not Linux

Tags: javascript, html, json, reactjs, webpack

So for my first ReactJS tutorial I was using a Ubuntu VM, and remember running into this problem because I forgot to install react and react-dom dependencies. I am now on windows, have made sure to install everything and I am getting the same error:

[image]

For my package.json I have this:

```
{
  "name": "github-battle",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "webpack.config.js",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.9",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.20.2",
    "webpack": "^3.11.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.11.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "create": "webpack"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

For my webpack.config.js

```
var path = require('path');
 var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

 module.exports = {
   entry: './app/index.js',
   output: {
     path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
     filename: 'index_bundle.js',
     publicPath: '/'
   },
   module: {
     rules: [
       { test: /\.(js)$/, use: 'babel-loader' },
       { test: /\.css$/, use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]}
     ]
   },
   devServer: {
     historyApiFallback: true,
    },
   plugins: [
     new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
       template: 'app/index.html'
     })
   ]
 };
```

index.js

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
require('./index.css');

class App extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div>Hello World</div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Is there something I have to do differently in windows?

Comment: You should double check the Line break type. You should change back to CR LR in Windows, LF in Linux. Use any code editor (e.g. Notepad++) to change it.

Comment: The thing is I made a brand new project, I did not copy over anything from my Linux VM

Comment: Nope. Even you create the file in Windows, there is still a chance the line break mode is incorrect.

Comment: I am using Notepad++, and it says the Format for Line Ending is Windows and Encoding is UTF-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to create a new project with all the file you pasted and I got the same error. I resolved it by running those 2 commands:

```
npm install --save react  
npm install --save react-dom
```

I also added a .babelrc file containing this:

```
{
  "presets": ["react"]
}
```

Comment: This is giving me more errors. It seems it doesn't recognize options. It says "Error options/query provided without loader (user loader + options in {CODE YOU GAVE ME HERE})"

Comment: I tried the new answer, but it threw the exact same error

Comment: Versions are all listed above under package.json. I do not have a .babelrc file. I never had one on linux, so maybe setup between windows and linux is a bit different

Comment: webpack is 5.6.0. I will post index.js above

Comment: Updated NPM and new message when using that preset is "ERROR in ./node_modules/lodash/lodash.js. Module build failed: Error: Couldn't find preset @babel/preset-env relative to directory C:\\ReactJS\\github-battle\\node_modules\\lodash"

Comment: Did that and I get my original error, see screenshot above

Comment: I tested the code you pasted and updated my answer with a solution that is working with what you pasted